# Add row number after splitting a string field

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table that contains 2 fields:
ID: text
Suggestions: string (comma separated values)

I would like to make a select query that would return a new numbered rows representing each suggestion with its own number as shown in the original string

Example:

[image]

Note: this ranking must be guaranteed to be the same everytime I run the query..

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If Version of your DB is *8.0+*, then `with recursive cte as` clause might be used as in the following select statement ( after needed DML's provided such as *create table* and *insert* statements ):

```
mysql> create table tab( ID int, suggestions varchar(25));
mysql> insert into tab values(1,'A,B,C');
mysql> insert into tab values(2,'D,E,F,G,H');
mysql> select q2.*,
              row_number() 
              over 
             (partition by q2.id order by q2.suggestion) as number 
  from 
(       
select distinct
       id, 
       substring_index(
        substring_index(suggestions, ',', q1.nr), 
        ',', 
        -1
       ) as suggestion
    from tab
    cross join
    (with recursive cte as
     (
      select 1 as nr
      union all
      select 1+nr from cte where nr<10
      )
     select * from cte) q1
) q2;

+------+------------+--------+
| id   | suggestion | number |
+------+------------+--------+
|    1 | A          |      1 |
|    1 | B          |      2 |
|    1 | C          |      3 |
|    2 | D          |      1 |
|    2 | E          |      2 |
|    2 | F          |      3 |
|    2 | G          |      4 |
|    2 | H          |      5 |
+------+------------+--------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Find [here](https://gist.github.com/avoidwork/3749973) same problem is solved.

```
https://gist.github.com/avoidwork/3749973
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a series of subqueries:

```
select id, substring_index(suggestions, ',', 1) as suggestion, 1
from example
where suggestions is not null
union all
select id, substring_index(substring_index(suggestions, ',', 2), ',', -1) as suggestion, 2
from example
where suggestions like '%,%'
union all
select id, substring_index(substring_index(suggestions, ',', 3), ',', -1) as suggestion, 3
from example
where suggestions like '%,%,%'
union all
select id, substring_index(substring_index(suggestions, ',', 4), ',', -1) as suggestion, 4
from example
where suggestions like '%,%,%,%'
union all
select id, substring_index(substring_index(suggestions, ',', 5), ',', -1) as suggestion, 5
from example
where suggestions like '%,%,%,%,%';
```

This can easily be extended if you have more than 5 options per id.

Comment: I have a huge and variable amount of suggestions per id, using this way would be a very long query!

Comment: @hemoali . . . You only need enough subqueries for the maximum number of suggests per id.